# Jquery help on sliding divs

Tags: jquery

Here is the HTML

```
<div id="projectheader">
Project 1
<span id="plus">+</span></div>
<div class="projectdrop">
<div id="orderheader"><span id="plus">+</span></div>
<div class="orderdrop"></div>
</div>

<div id="projectheader" style="margin-top: 20px;">
Project2
<span id="plus">+</span></div>
<div class="projectdrop">
<div id="orderheader"><span id="plus">+</span></div>
<div class="orderdrop"></div>

</div>
```

Im working on a site where the projects are created dynamically on the back end and the info is inserted into the projectheader on the front end. So there could be many div's with the ID of projectheader on the same page.
What I'm looking to do is click on the + div and slide down the projectdrop. This is not a problem with only one project on the page but not able to get it working when multiple projectheader are on the page. I want to be able to slidedown only the specific projectheader I click on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ids are suppose to be unique.

Comment: Have you considered some kind of javascript library,  i.e. jquery?  jquery ui has a nice tabbed widget that looks like it would do what you want.  If you want to do it yourself in your own javasscript,  at least go look at the demo for jquery ui tab,  and it may give you some good ideas.  It will illustrate what the previous comment said about ids being unique,  among other things.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I highly recommend you rectify the duplicate ID issue, because it's not only bad practice but generates problems like this.  It would seem like `projectheader` (and most of your other "IDs") are better used as classes, not IDs.

If you just want a solution that works however, I believe this will do the trick:

```
$('.plus').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().next('.projectdrop').slideDown();
}
```

Just change those spans to have the class plus instead of id plus.  You *cannot* select multiple things using the one ID.

Note also that having to use the order of DOM elements in order to form relationships between them can be considered bad practice.  It is better to wrap related elements inside a `div` or other appropriate element, which in turn has an ID or other identifying property attached to it.  For example:

```
<div class="project" id="project1">
    <header>
        Project 1
        <span class="plus">+</span>
    </header>
    <div class="drop">
        <div class="order">
            <header>
                <span class="plus">+</span>
            </header>
            <div class="drop">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: $('#plus').click() will only works for the first matched element. I can count 4 in 'the little sample' code. So as you suggest, id should be replaced with class.

Comment: While you are at it, convert all your ids to classes there. They should all be classes.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

```
$(document).ready (function() {
$('.plus').on('click', function() {
 $(this).parent().next('.projectdrop').slideToggle('slow');
```

Another question. How would I replace the + div with a - when the projectdrop is open?

Thanks

Comment: You want the `.html()` method.  To change the div to a - run `$('.plus').html('-');`

Comment: Also I realise that my previous answer is incorrect, your HTML was confusing due to a lack of indentation. I think your DOM structure should be revised, it doesn't quite make hierarchical sense. However, your solution is correct. I'll fix mine now.